# Cypress img elements attribute checking

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to check if all images on my page have the Alt attribute. I thought doing the following would do that but it doesn't check things correctly and just gives me an everything is good when I know it's not. 

`cy.get('img').should('have.attr',
 'alt' );`

Is there an easy solution other than many go through the page and build a selector for every image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check each element, you can use `.each`:

```js
cy.get('img').each($el => {
  cy.wrap($el).should('have.attr', 'alt')
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I tried the same kinda thing before but used get instead of wrap